# Custom Windows shell hosted on the network

Tags: windows, networking, shell

We have a custom kiosk-style executable that we are using as a shell on Windows 8.1 machines.  We'd like to host it on the network so that it's easy to update as desired.

The problem we have is that the machines boot so quickly - before the network finishes initializing - that the shell is not available, so Explorer launches instead.

We have Group Policy set to wait for the network before logon but that doesn't seem to impact this.

How can we ensure the network is there before continuing?

Comment: A startup script that waits for a successful ping to the server hosting the shell, perhaps?  It may need to kill Explorer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving this in a similar somewhat like Tony suggested in his comment, but the details are different.  We created a user login script and set group policy set to run logon scripts synchronously.  In the script we have a

```
timeout 8
```

which is long enough for these machines to come up fully on the network; after the script exits, Windows then starts our shell.